# Getting Exception while calling soap webservice

Tags: java, android, .net, web-services, soap

When I am using SoapUI to call [this web service](http://www.ocrwebservice.com/services/OCRWebService.asmx?op=OCRWebServiceRecognize)  I am getting the correct response but when I implement this in android, I am getting the below exception,

> system.web.services.protocols.soapheaderexception (some information is missing).

This is what I tried,

```
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.ocrwebservice.com/services/OCRWebService.asmx");
       StringEntity se = new StringEntity(SOAPRequestXML,HTTP.UTF_8);
       se.setContentType("text/xml");
       httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
       httppost.setEntity(se);
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = 
        (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

I tried other combinations also like,
               `httppost.setHeader("Accept-Charset","utf-8")`
and
               `httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8")`

But nothing worked.

The error says,

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: WSE012: The input was not a valid SOAP message because the following information is missing: action.

Comment: Can you please add stacktace ?

Comment: Can you share the wsdl?

Comment: http://www.ocrwebservice.com/services/OCRWebService.asmx   this is the wsdl

Comment: @ Paresh  Looking at the service, How can I set action, can you help in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: WSE012: The input
>   was not a valid SOAP message because the following information is
>   missing: action.

=> As per the above exception, I can say you forgot to set Action.

Try:

```
String SOAP_ACTION = "http://stockservice.contoso.com/wse/samples/2005/10/OCRWebServiceAvailablePages";
httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);
```

Comment: @user2443383 not an issue!! Enjoy